# Postgresql array intersections on jsonb

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

Given the following data stored in the db:

```
{
  myArray: [
    {key: 'a'},
    {key: 'b'},
    {key: 'c'}
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to query for intersections as follows?

```
[
  {key: 'a'},
  {key: 'd'}
]
```

You see, that `{key: 'a'}` is the intersection even though `{key: 'a'}` does not match.

Answer (score 0):

You can do intersections on `jsonb` with a simple `JOIN` & the `jsonb_array_elements` function:

```
select     element
from       tbl
cross join jsonb_array_elements(tbl.jsonb_column -> 'myArray') a1(element)
inner join jsonb_array_elements(jsonb '[{"key":"a"},{"key":"d"}]') a2(element) using (element);

--  element
-----------------
-- '{"key": "a"}'
```

http://rextester.com/IUGZ15294